# printf() structures in Java

Tags: java

I am using printf to structure a table with three columns and have run into a bit of trouble.

I am currently using:

```
System.out.printf("%-10s %33s %5.2f\n", "New Price:", "$", newPrice);
System.out.printf("%-10s %28s %1.2f\n", "Depreciation Amount:", "$", -Dep1);
System.out.printf("%-10s %23s %3.2f\n", "Other Depreciation Amount:", "$", -Dep2);
System.out.printf("%-10s %21s %5.2f\n\n", "Current Market Value:", "$", curVal);
System.out.printf("%-10s %32s %6.2f\n\n", "Other Amount:", "$", otherAmount);
```

Which gives me an output of:

```
New Purchase Price:                                 $ 60000.00
Age Depreciation Amount:                            $ -18000.00
Distance Depreciation Amount:                       $ -9600.00
Estimated Current Market Value:                     $ 32400.00

Base Premium Amount:                                $ 1620.00
```

I can't work out how to adjust my printf to make it appear as:

```
New Purchase Price:                                 $  60000.00
Age Depreciation Amount:                            $ -18000.00
Distance Depreciation Amount:                       $  -9600.00
Estimated Current Market Value:                     $  32400.00

Base Premium Amount:                                $   1620.00
```

How would I achieve this?

Cheers

Comment: Try using `%-50s %s %9.2f%n` in all of them. Or better yet, inline the dollar sign: `%-50s $ %9.2f%n`

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is how:

```
System.out.printf("%-30s %2s %8.2f\n", "New Price:", "$", newPrice);
System.out.printf("%-30s %2s %8.2f\n", "Depreciation Amount:", "$",
            -Dep1);
System.out.printf("%-30s %2s %8.2f\n", "Other Depreciation Amount:",
            "$", -Dep2);
System.out.printf("%-30s %2s %8.2f\n\n", "Current Market Value:", "$",
            curVal);
System.out.printf("%-30s %2s %8.2f\n\n", "Other Amount:", "$",
            otherAmount);
```

1) The width is the total width, including the period and the fraction.

2) Don't calculate manually the width of your constant, the computer is better at it.

3) In future, post the actual code the corresponds with the results, rather than an approximation.